# git log a specific HEAD~N

Tags: git, git-log

Is there any way to just show the output of `git log` a number of commits ago?

I tried, e.g. `git log HEAD~3` but that seems to show everything, not just the entry for `HEAD~3` (three commits ago from `HEAD`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, `git show HEAD~3` will display the single commit object (including a diff of files it changed, by default).

Comment: Thanks! I think that `git show HEAD~3 --summary` specfically would return the equivalent snippet that I see in `git log`

Comment: @user815423426 Right. Note that other switches like `--stat` may be useful, too.

Comment: also `git log -1 HEAD~3`, if you prefer the various options that you can give to `git log` that `git show` doesn't support

Comment: Note that `git show` has at least one oddball bug currently (it doesn't respect --pretty for merge commits) that `git log -1` does not exhibit.  They should both be equivalent though.